# PHP por qué array_map y array_filter se llaman al revés

Tags: php

Siempre que voy a usar uno de esos dos métodos tengo que leer la documentación porque la impronta de [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php) es:

```
array_filter ( array $array , callable $callback )
```

Mientras que la de [array_map](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) es

```
array_map ( callable $callback , array $array )
```

Y nunca estoy seguro de cual es cuál. Dependiendo del IDE yo sé que algunos sugieren parámetros, pero la verdad es que detesto PHPStorm por la lentitud.

Acá estoy omitiendo parámetros opcionales y pregunto:

- Existe alguna librería o buena practica para abstraer este inconveniente y no tener que mirar los docs a cada rato?
- Por qué PHP las definió asi, ¿Tiene alguna ventaja?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para trabajar con arrays yo siempre uso [Arrayzy](https://github.com/bocharsky-bw/Arrayzy) para evitarme estas cosas. Y no, no hay ventaja alguna.

El desarrollo del lenguaje PHP siempre ha estado salpicado por la polémica debido a la falta de estandarización a la hora de darle nombre a sus funciones (entre otras cosas). Por suerte, parece ser que con la salida de PHP7 están empezando a hacer las cosas algo mejor últimamente. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quería añadir a las respuestas mi propia solución: [Underscore.php](http://anahkiasen.github.io/underscore-php/). Está nombrado así por el clásico [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/) aunque no es exactamente un port.

Volviendo a la pregunta original. Supongamos que tengo un array:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Quiero obtener un array que liste sólo los números pares, y otro array que liste los cuadrados de cada elemento. En php tendría que hacer:

```
<?php

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$pares = array_filter($array, function ($value) {
    return $value / 2 === intval($value / 2);
});

$cuadrados = array_map(function ($value) {
    return $value * $value;
}, $array);
```

Que, como se ve, tienen los parámetros invertidos.

En Underscore.php, puedes usar en cambio:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Underscore\Types\Arrays;

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$pares = Arrays::filter($array, function ($value) {
    return $value / 2 === intval($value / 2);
});

$cuadrados = Arrays::each($array, function ($value) {
    return $value * $value;
});
```

Ojo, Underscore.php delega en los métodos de PHP por debajo, así que `Arrays::map` espera los parámetros invertidos. Por eso se usa `Arrays::each`.

Esta librería permite además usar una sintaxis encadenando los métodos:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \Underscore\Underscore;

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$pares = Underscore::from($array)->filter(function ($value) {
    return $value / 2 === intval($value / 2);
})->obtain();

$cuadrados = Underscore::from($array)->each(function ($value) {
    return $value * $value;
})->obtain();
```

Con esto, puedo obtener por ejemplo sólo los cuadrados de los números pares:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \Underscore\Underscore;

$cuadradospares = Underscore::from($array)->filter(function ($value) {
    return $value / 2 === intval($value / 2);
})->each(function ($value) {
    return $value * $value;
})->obtain();
```

En fin... ya casi no uso PHP, pero me encontré con esta pregunta que hice hace tiempo y quise contar cómo lo resolví en su momento.